# Classic download Manager on Firefox >20

Tags: firefox

On my users computers, Firefox has autoupdated to 20.0, and that's a big problem, because of the new download manager window. They cannot get used to it, they call me constantly at the intercom "hey, where are my downloads???".

If someone knows an hidden setting in the about:config that would restore the old download window, that would save my life

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2033461/how-to-switch-back-to-firefoxs-old-download-manager.html)

> 1. Open a new tab.
> 2. Type about:config, then press Enter.
> 3. Paste the following into the search field: `browser.download.useToolkitUI`
> 4. Under the Value field, right-click false and then click Toggle. That should set the Value to "true."
> 5. Restart Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open a new tab.
2. Type about:config, then press Enter.
3. Paste the following into the search field: `browser.download.useToolkitUI`
4. Under the Value field, right-click false and then click Toggle. That should set the Value to "true."
5. Restart Firefox.

Now, when you click that Download button or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, you'll get the old-school download manager. And if you decide you prefer the new one after all, just repeat the process.

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.ghacks.net/2013/04/02/firefox-20-0-find-out-what-is-new/

> The new feature brings along several advanced configuration
>   preferences that you can modify. One of them lets you turn the feature
>   off so that you can go back to the old download manager. Let me show
>   you how that is done:
>
> Type `about:config` into the Firefox address bar and hit the enter key afterwards.
>   Confirm that you will be careful if you open this page for the first time.
>   Type the following parameters into the search form at the top
>   `browser.download.useToolkitUI` - This turns the new download panel on or off. 
>   The default setting is false which means that it is turned
>   on.
>   Double-click the entry to set it to true and turn off the new
>   download manager.