# Shortcut to Open Quick Download Manager in Firefox 20 or above

Tags: firefox

Firefox 20 introduced a new Download Manager with their version 20 release. Like with any change, some people have complained about the change, and [want to revert to the old behavior](https://superuser.com/questions/581293/classic-download-manager-on-firefox-20). I don't mind the new Download Manager, but the change does break my workflow.

Formerly, to check on my downloads, I would press `Ctrl`+`J`, scan the list quickly, then hit `Esc` to continue with my browsing. But, the new Download Manager opens in a full window, which does not close on `Esc`. I have noticed that Firefox also has some sort of Download quick viewer, which opens when I select the Download toolbar item. This shows a quick dialog window, which will close when it loses focus or I press `Esc`, and I actually prefer this for viewing my downloads.

So, do I have a keyboard shortcut to open this quick view? Or, can I re-map `Ctrl`+`J` to open this view instead of the full Download Manager?

Comment: Are you talking about the top right hand side download bar?

Comment: On new installs, you can find it in the top right hand side, yes. I am talking about the window/dialog that opens upon selection of that button.

Comment: @pamswim, I have answered your question on how to enable the old version of the download manager :)

Comment: Yes, but the question I referenced in the link in the question answers the question of how to revert to the old version of the Download Manager.

Comment: I don't know how to activate the new Download button menu with the keyboard, but I believe the big Download Manager window can be closed with Ctrl+W as usual. If your Firefox window is always maximised (i.e. the Download button's position remains constant), it might be possible to cook up an AutoHotkey script to click the button, with the script being activated by a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have altered my muscle memory since I posted this question.

I now can hit `Ctrl`+`J` and `Ctrl`+`W` rapidly without thinking about it. Thanks [to Karan](https://superuser.com/q/590832/45163#comment726404_590832) for helping me adjust my habits.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

This is how to get the old Download Manager for Firefox 20 or above

Step 01:

type in "about:config" in the url bar

Step 02:

Search for "browser.download.useToolkitUI"

Step 03:

Change the value to "true"

[image]

That's it, now you can use the old Download Manager for Firefox and use the `ESC` as you wish :)

[image]

Comment: Looks like you didn't even bother to read the question properly. The OP even linked to a previous question where these steps are provided.

Comment: @Karan my bad I think I missed on the URL on the question I didn't see that.